# How to list twitter tweets that are shared from Instagram app

Tags: twitter

Utilizing the [Twitter search API](https://dev.twitter.com/rest/public/search), I'm fetching tweets from a specific Twitter account

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/search/tweets.json?tweet_mode=extended&q=from%3Asweetheatmn3+filter%3Aimages
```

Unfortunately, the API returns the regular tweets but does not return tweets shared from the Instagram APP

Is there any specific solution or this is a bug from Twitter side?

Update: Twitter search API is not complete and it may not return all the tweets and for complete results, the streaming API should be used.

Refernce:https://twittercommunity.com/t/shared-from-instagram-app-tweets-are-not-returned/93058/6

Answer (score 0):

Twitter search API is not complete and it may not return all the tweets and for complete results, the timeline endpoint should be used.

So I used

```
https://api.twitter.com/1.1/statuses/user_timeline.json?tweet_mode=extended&screen_name=sweetheatmn3
```

Instead of the search endpoint

Refernce: https://twittercommunity.com/t/shared-from-instagram-app-tweets-are-not-returned/93058/6